# Sharding schemes

Tags: database, sharding, database-partitioning

I am looking for some sharding schemes, and I also need some literature on that. So far the ones I have found:

```
- Key based partitioning 
- Vertical partitioning
- Directory based partitioning
```

Any more ideas on sharding? And i will be glad if you can provide some literature on that or some books etc.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for [ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com), a provider of a complete MySQL scale-out solution an "automatic sharding machine" if you like... We've seen a thing or 2 about shrading...

We have some good resources about key-based sharding (hash, range, list) and data distribution on our site:
http://www.scalebase.com/products/database-sharding/
http://www.scalebase.com/resources/webinars/ - (search for "WEBINAR – 10.23.12: Benefits of Automatic Data Distribution")

I also invite you to look at my blog, posts such as: http://database-scalability.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/partial-partitioning-and-sharding.html

I'll be happy to answer any question or give more material!